# Docker image with Rstudio, Jupyter and Conda / Mamba

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm getting started into docker and have a few questions, hope these aren't too stupid. I want to make a container with Conda, such that different environments can be called to access a common shared folder.

```
---| my_container
-----|conda installation
-----|conda env1
--------|rstudio
--------|R
--------|R packages
-----|conda env2
--------|jupyter
--------|python3
--------|python packages
-----|conda env3
--------|jupyter
--------|python3
--------|other python packages
```

Depending on my needs, I would call `env1` if I wanted to run a given set of R packages in rstudio, or `env2` if I wanted to run a set of python packages in jupyter, or `env3` if I wanted to run yet another set of python / jupyter packages.

I am now able to launch R and Jupyter from browser from the container (through the , as I have used `docker-compose` with the following `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
  1 version: "3.8"
  2 services:
  3   rstudio:
  4     environment:
  5       - USER=username
  6       - PASSWORD=password
  7     image: "rocker/tidyverse:latest"
  8     volumes:
  9         - ~/GitHub/dockertest/notebooks/:/home/username/dockertest/notebooks/
 10     container_name: rstudio
 11     ports:
 12       - 8787:8787
 13
 14   jupyter:
 15     image: 'jupyter/datascience-notebook:latest'
 16     ports:
 17       - 8888:8888
 18     environment:
 19         - USER=username
 20         - PASSWORD=password
 21     volumes:
 22       - ~/GitHub/dockertest/notebooks/:/home/username/dockertest/notebooks/
 23     working_dir: /home/username/dockertest/notebooks/
 24     container_name: jupyter
```

and I have run `docker-compose up -d --build` to create each image.

### Questions:

1. I am confused as to how I would go about creating different environments in the container. If I was in conda, I knew how to `activate` and edit each environment. How would I go about this in docker?
2. Is it better to simply create different 3 different images (containers?) that would correspond to each of the `env1`, `env2` and `env3`?

Comment: I'd recommend creating 3 different images, yes.  If you can do it with plain Python pip, it will be easier to set up than Conda; ideally you wouldn't have a virtual environment setup at all (but each image provides isolation from other Pythons).

Comment: Check out this [repo](https://github.com/borundev/machine_learning_docker/tree/master/multiple_conda_environments) Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your comments DavidMaze and sujay-pillai. It seems sensible to create 3 different images (each with a full installation, without even needing conda). If any of you has any quick instructions that you can post as answer I'll be happy to accept it.
thanks a lot